# Why use `defsubst` in `man.el`?

Tags: functions

I recently noticed an issue in `man.el`, in which sections in `Man--sections` are listed backwards. That is, the value is is something like:

```
(#("SEE ALSO" 0 8
   (face Man-overstrike))
 #("COPYRIGHT" 0 9
   (face Man-overstrike))
 #("REPORTING BUGS" 0 14
   (face Man-overstrike))
 #("AUTHOR" 0 6
   (face Man-overstrike))
 #("EXAMPLES" 0 8
   (face Man-overstrike))
 #("DESCRIPTION" 0 11
   (face Man-overstrike))
 #("SYNOPSIS" 0 8
   (face Man-overstrike))
 #("NAME" 0 4
   (face Man-overstrike)))
```

This is because `Man-build-section-alist` scans the buffer from `(point-min)` to `(point-max)`, `push`-ing values onto `Man--sections` as it goes.

I wanted to change this behavior so that the sections are in the correct order, which matters to `helm-mode`.

However, changing the `Man-build-section-alist` function, then re-evaluating it doesn't do any good, because it's defined with `defsubst` instead of `defun`. `defsubst` [inlines functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Inline-Functions.html), which means that, when the file is byte-compiled, the function definition is directly inserted where the function is called. This means that redefining/evaluating the function doesn't work, since the bytecode is not changed.

`defsubst` offers a performance benefit, but is there really any reason to use it for a command like `Man-build-section-alist`? Most functions in `man.el` use `defun`, and I can't imagine that the performance benefit matters on hardware from the past 15 years.

Comment: IMHO, there is rarely a good reason to use `defsubst` nowadays. People sometimes think that a function (often a tiny one, but that makes no difference) will never need to be used by anyone (a user, using Lisp). They are almost always wrong in principle, and almost almost always wrong in practice. I think it comes from a shortsighted view of Lisp users, and perhaps from an ingrained notion of a separation between "developers" and "users" - a notion that some bring to Emacs from other kinds of programming, in other contexts (e.g., not for user interaction). -- Just one opinion.

Comment: If speed matters, use `defmacro`, not `defsubst`. If you need a function because it will be `funcall`ed or `apply`ed or mapped, use `defun`, not `defsubst`. Show me a case where `defsubst` is used and I'm pretty sure it should not be used.

Comment: I'm not sure `defmacro` should be used just for a performance boost. Macros are used to extend the language, and carry costs (e.g. more difficult to reason about and debug).

Comment: @TianxangXiong: Agreed. I was contrasting it with `defsubst`.

Comment: @Drew "If speed matters, use `defmacro`, not `defsubst`" - that makes no sense, `defmacro` has all the drawbacks of `defsubst` and additionally the code will be more complicated by the multiple phases of evaluation (I agree that `defsubst` is usually a bad idea, typically premature optimization)

Comment: @npostavs: Using a macro saves only a function call, yes. And that makes little difference nowadays. But *saving a function call was the reason people used `defsubst`* - that, combined with the ability to be invoked as a function (which `defmacro` lacks). And for that reason (alone), `defmacro` is better than `defsubst`. (I cannot edit my older comment to clarify it.)

Comment: FWIW, Emacs-25 comes with a new `define-inline` macro which can be used in those cases where performance is important.  `define-inline` is a kind of halfway between `defsubst` and `defmacro`: it defines a *function* (i.e. `funcall`able) but you can optimize it when it's inlined.  It's not as simple to use as `defsubst`, but results in more efficient code.

Comment: Neat, but `define-inline` seems like a chore to use, with `inline-quote`, `inline-letevals`, and a whole bunch of other macros to go along with it.

Comment: BTW, you might like to `M-x report-emacs-bug` saying that it's OK for a defsubst function to be inlined, but it should be de/re-inlined whenever its definition changes (i.e. Emacs should keep track of those inlinings and keep them uptodate).

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, I disagree with a general ban on `defsubst`, but these two uses of `defsubst` in man.el seem like clear errors, indeed.  Basically any function which contains a loop will spend much more time in its loop than entering/leaving the function itself, so using `defsubst` is just not appropriate in such a case.

Comment: You disagree that `defsubst` is no longer useful, but you do not say which cases you find it *useful* for. (And no one has suggested "banning" it.)

Comment: It is useful in some cases in order to circumvent the low-efficiency of function calls.  I.e. when the function is called *very* often, and when the runtime of the function is (usually) *very* short.

Comment: I'd love to see an example, with some stats about performance. All I've seen so far just represents an inconvenience for someone who wants to actually use the `defsubst` as a real (runtime) function. I don't think I've seen a case where performance matters in decades. Probably such a case could be concocted, but I'd be curious to see a real such case.

Comment: @Drew: here's an [example where `defsubst` is useful  (it fixes the "recursive autoload" issue)](https://github.com/dzop/emacs-jupyter/issues/172#issuecomment-599124738)

Comment: @jfs: they don't need to make it a `defsubst` in order for the whole definition to be put into the autoload file.  They could use `;;;###autoload \n (progn (defun ...))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why man.el uses defsubst—you'd have to ask whoever wrote the function—but I'm sure that it's not really needed.  I agree with Drew: Nowadays you shouldn't use defsubst anymore.

But then you shouldn't patch or advice other libraries as well, unless absolutely necessary. And the inverse order of a list doesn't strike me as a good reason for advicing.

I'm not sure why Helm should require this variable to be in proper order, but you should always be able to point it to another variable that holds the `reverse` list.

But please **do not use advices**.

Comment: I certainly wasn't going to modify Helm to advise the the `Man-build-sections-alist` function. If anything, it's the `Man` function that should be modified to return values in proper order..

Comment: I was going to say something similar to lunaryorn: *Why does the order matter?* (But I disagree about "do not use advices", except I agree that it makes sense to minimize doing so.)

Comment: Why shouldn't the order matter? If I know that a collection is ordered, I won't have to sort it again. Besides, the `push`-`nreverse` idiom is [common in Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/they-called-it-lisp-for-a-reason-list-processing.html).